# MSAL.NET On-Behalf-Of Flow API scopes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, maui, microsoft-entra-id

I am creating a .NET MAUI app that uses the Azure DevOps API through a .NET 8 web API via the on behalf of flow. I am running into an issue where the on behalf of call is throwing an error because of an invalid scope:

```
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation offline_access openid profile' does not exist. Trace ID: .... Correlation ID: .... Timestamp: 2024-01-13 16:16:31Z","error_codes":[70011],"timestamp":"2024-01-13 16:16:31Z","trace_id":"1...","correlation_id":"..."}
```

The initial call to my protected web API seems to be working fine because the controller is protected with the [Authorize] attribute and I am able to hit a break point inside of one of the endpoints. My web API has the following configuration:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "ClientId": "<WEB API CLIENT ID>",
  "TenantId": "common",
  "ClientSecret": "WEB API CLIENT SECRET"
}
```

And the relevant controller looks like this:

```
[Route("api/devops/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class CodeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly string _scope;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
    private readonly ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions _applicationOptions;
    private readonly IConfidentialClientApplication _app;
    private readonly UserAssertion _userAssertion;

    public CodeController(IHttpContextAccessor context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _scope = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation";
        _context = context;
        _applicationOptions = new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions();
        configuration.Bind("AzureAD", _applicationOptions);
        _app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .CreateWithApplicationOptions(_applicationOptions)
            .Build();
        _userAssertion = new UserAssertion(context.HttpContext?.Request.Headers.Authorization[0]?.Split(" ")[1], "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");

    }

    // GET: api/devops/<CodeController>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string organization = "takedowndevelopment")
    {
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult ar = await _app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new[] { _scope }, _userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            <BREAKPOINT BEING HIT>
        }
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I have exposed an API on the app registration for the web API and I am passing that scope with the initial authorization interaction in the mobile app (api://<WEB_API_CLIENT_ID>/access_as_user). The web API also has API permissions to access Azure DevOps APIs with `user_impersonation`. Based on the error message, I would assume I am misunderstanding how I am supposed to be configuring the scopes/using them in requests. Has anyone had any similar experiences?

I have been fumbling around with this for a few weeks now and I have scoured the Microsoft docs for .NET 8 with MSAL.NET and .NET MAUI but they are not as good as they could be. I have included a diagram of the system below:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: May these samples help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-api